# C# calculate conditional returns

Tags: c#, list, math

My question is about calculating conditional returns overtime. It's a bit hard to describe, if some parts are not clear, please ask me to clarify. I have a C# WinForm application that read in two series of data, one is product return numbers overtime, and the other is index return numbers overtime. When index return number is positive, I call that period a "up market". I created a sub-list to store all product return numbers corresponding to each "up market", and another sub-list to store all product return numbers corresponding to each "down market".

```
for (int i = 0; i < ProductReturnRawData.Count; i++)
{
   if (primaryIndexReturnRawData[i] >=  0)
   {
      upMarketWealth.Add(1 + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100);
   }

   else if (primaryIndexReturnRawData[i] < 0)
   {
      downMarketWealth.Add(1 + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100);
   }
}
```

After creating the upMarketWealth list, I use another function to calculate the product return given the market is up.

```
private double check_period_upMarket(
    List<double> upMarketWealth, int months, int go_back = 0)
{
   double return_calc = 1;
   for (int i = upMarketWealth.Count - 1 - go_back; 
        i > upMarketWealth.Count - (1 + months + go_back); i--)
   return_calc *= upMarketWealth[i];
   return Math.Pow(return_calc, 12.0 / upMarketWealth.Count) - 1;
}
```

At the end, I call this check_period_upMarket function like this:

```
StatsTable[Tuple.Create(period, "Up-Market Return")] = 
    check_period_upMarket(upMarketWealth, 12);
```

So here I want to know within the last 12 months, how many months are up market (upMarketWealth.Count suppose gives me the answer), and the annualized returns of the product when the market is up.

I calculate the number on Excel manually, it doesn't match the result of this code.

**Example:** index return over the last 12 months {-0.08
0.95
-1.34
-2.36
3.25
5.24
-0.88
-0.38
1.39
0.48
0.73
0.57
}     product return over the same period {-0.03
0.12
-0.06
-2.03
1.15
2.06
0.35
0.47
1.65
-0.20
0.79
1.17
}.

So upMarket list should have {0.12, 1.15, 2.06, 1.65, -0.20, 0.79, 1.17}. Create a wealth list by

```
upMarketWealth.Add(1 + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100);
```

then

```
return_calc *= upMarketWealth[i];
return Math.Pow(return_calc, 12.0 / upMarketWealth.Count) - 1;
```

The correct answer should be 12.16%, while the code has 10%. Please help me find the error here. Please ask me clarify if something is not clear.

Comment: Maybe you've got integer division happening somewhere you weren't expecting. What type is `primaryIndexReturnRawData`?

Comment: Have you tried appending d to the end of all of your constants, for instance upMarketWealth.Add(1d + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100d);?

Comment: I haven't, but I don't think this can solve the problem since I have other calculations which work fine without appending d. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

As presented, the code won't work at all but throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

The problem is by building `upMarketWealth` and `downMarketWealth` lists you effectively shrink the data — omit entries for months that aren't 'up' or 'down' respectively. You should instead place a `1.0` into the list. On the other hand, the for cycle in `check_period_upMarket` doesn't respect this behavior, and calculates incorrect bounds. Also, the `Math.Pow` call at then end incorrectly assumes that the count of items in the list corresponds to the number of 'up' months. Instead, this should be passed in as a parameter.

Working minimal example producing the expected output:

```
private double check_period_upMarket(List<double> upMarketWealth, int upMonths, int months, int go_back = 0)
{
    double return_calc = 1;
    for (int i = upMarketWealth.Count - 1 - go_back; i > upMarketWealth.Count - 1 - go_back - months; i--)
    {
        return_calc *= upMarketWealth[i];
    }
    return Math.Pow(return_calc, 12.0 / upMonths) - 1;
}

void Main()
{
    List<double> primaryIndexReturnRawData = new List<double> {-0.08, 0.95, -1.34, -2.36, 3.25, 5.24, -0.88, -0.38, 1.39,  0.48, 0.73, 0.57 };
    List<double> ProductReturnRawData = new List<double> {     -0.03, 0.12, -0.06, -2.03, 1.15, 2.06,  0.35,  0.47, 1.65, -0.20, 0.79, 1.17 };

    List<double> upMarketWealth = new List<double>();
    List<double> downMarketWealth = new List<double>();

    int upMonths = 0;
    int downMonths = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ProductReturnRawData.Count; i++)
    {
        if (primaryIndexReturnRawData[i] >=  0)
        {
            upMarketWealth.Add(1 + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100);
            downMarketWealth.Add(1.0);
            upMonths++;
        }
        else if (primaryIndexReturnRawData[i] < 0)
        {
            upMarketWealth.Add(1.0);
            downMarketWealth.Add(1 + ProductReturnRawData[i] / 100);
            downMonths++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(check_period_upMarket(upMarketWealth, upMonths, 12));
    // output: 0.121499259430152
}
```